# Bayes Theorem Application Problem?

Tags: probability

I have a question for which seems to be application of Bayes Theorem.

(Adapted from the battle game "Bowser's Bigger Blast” from Nintendo's Mario Party 4) In this game, 4 players compete in a deadly game of chance against each other. On a stage, there are 5 detonators. One is connected to a bomb while the other four are disconnected and will have no effect. Player 1 must go first and push one of the five detonators. If he is unlucky enough to choose the live detonator, he will set off the bomb and lose the game (and his life). If he chooses one of the four "duds”, he is safe and will remove that detonator from the game. At that point, player 2 must choose one of the four remaining detonators, and so on. If all four players are lucky enough to survive their choices, then the state is reset (with the five detonators and one randomly selected to be live) and the procedure is repeated, until a player eventually loses. Is this a fair game? Or, is one player more likely to lose than the others? That is, find the probability of each player losing the game.

Pr(first player loses) =

Pr(2nd player loses) =

Pr(3rd player loses) =

Pr(4th player loses) =

I could not actually apply Bayes theorem to this problem. so I counted possibilities for each possible event.

1st Player lose = 1 out of 5  = 0.2

2nd player lose = Assuming 1st player wins (4 possibilities) -> 2nd choice all possibilities (4*4) and lose possibility (4*1) = 4*1/4*4 = 1/4 = 0.25

3rd player lose -> 12/4*3*3 = 12/36 = 1/3

4th player lose - > 24/4*3*4 = 1/2

And I got all wrong and my friend who put in 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 for all players got also wrong as well. Am I solving this in wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

For each round (resetting the detonators), it is equally likely for each to die, and for all to live, as I'll show:

p(1st player lose in this round): $\frac {1}{5}=0.2$

p(2nd player lose in this round): $\frac {4}{5}*\frac {1}{4}=0.2$

p(3rd player lose in this round): $\frac {4}{5}*\frac {3}{4}*\frac {1}{3}=0.2$

p(4th player lose in this round): $\frac {4}{5}*\frac {3}{4}*\frac {2}{3}*\frac {1}{2}=0.2$

p(all players live): $\frac {4}{5}*\frac {3}{4}*\frac {2}{3}*\frac {1}{2}=0.2$

So for each round the game is fair, so for all rounds the game is fair, so the probabilities are 0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25.